# Not iterating contacts through ipairs properly

Tags: lua

I have got the following code:

```
local Enemy = Enemy
local g = {}

local contactList = {}
local groupChats = {L"Solo", L"Party", L"Warband"}
local chatPrefix = {L"/s", L"/p", L"/wb"}


local function getGroupType()
  if (IsWarBandActive()) then
    return 3
  end
  if (GetNumGroupmates() > 0) then
    return 2
  end 
  return 1
end

local function getChatPrefix()
  local gtype = getGroupType()
  return chatPrefix[gtype]
end

local function getChatType()
  local gtype = getGroupType()
  return groupChats[gtype]
end


local function getGroupNames()
  local names = {}
  local group = GetGroupData()
  for _, member in ipairs(group) do
    if (member.name ~= nil) then
      names[#names+1] = member.name
    end
  end
  return names
end

local function getWarbandNames()
  local names = {}
  local warband = GetBattlegroupMemberData()
  for _, party in ipairs(warband) do
    for a = 1, 6 do
      if (party.players[a] ~= nil) then
        if (party.players[a].name ~= Enemy.playerName) then
          names[#names+1] = party.players[a].name
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return names
end


function Enemy.getChatPrefix()
  return getChatPrefix()
end

function Enemy.IntercomInitialize ()
    
    Enemy.intercom = g
    g.queue = {}
  
  
  RegisterEventHandler(SystemData.Events.BATTLEGROUP_UPDATED, "Enemy.intercomGroupUpdated")
  RegisterEventHandler(SystemData.Events.GROUP_UPDATED, "Enemy.intercomGroupUpdated")
  RegisterEventHandler (SystemData.Events.GROUP_PLAYER_ADDED, "Enemy.intercomGroupUpdated")

    -- events
    Enemy.AddEventHandler ("Intercom", "ChatTextArrived", Enemy.Intercom_OnChatTextArrived) 
    Enemy.AddEventHandler ("Intercom", "BroadcastMessageAsk", Enemy.Intercom_OnBroadcastMessageAsk)
    Enemy.AddEventHandler ("Intercom", "BroadcastMessageInvite", Enemy.Intercom_OnBroadcastMessageInvite)
    

    if (Enemy.CanSendIntercomMessage ()) then
      --table.insert (data, L"You're currently in '"..g.name..L"' intercom channel with subId: '"..g.subId..L"'")
      table.insert (data, L"You're currently in intercom channel: '"..g.subId..L"'")
    else
      table.insert (data, L"You're currently not in any intercom channel.")
    end
        
    table.insert (data, L"Left-click to open intercom channel dialog.")
  end )
    
    
    Enemy.TriggerEvent ("IntercomInitialized")
end

function Enemy.intercomGroupUpdated()
  local gtype = getGroupType()
  --d(gtype)
  contactList = {}
  if (gtype == 2) then
    contactList = getGroupNames()
  elseif (gtype == 3) then
    contactList = getWarbandNames()
  end
  --d(contactList)
end

function Enemy.Intercom_OnChatTextArrived (t, from, text)
  local data = Enemy.Split(towstring(text), L":")
  if (text:find(L"EnemyAddon")) then
      local commandFlag = true
    -- .alert someone Scatterpack:Scatterpack:EnemyAddon:Mark:Neborhest Bat:N:474:
    --        address from       :subId      :EnemyAddon:command
    if (text:find(L":Ask:")) then
      Enemy.Intercom_OnBroadcastMessageAsk (data[2], data[1])
    end
    if (text:find(L":Invite:")) then
      Enemy.Intercom_OnBroadcastMessageInvite(L"", data[1], data[2])
    end
    if (data[2] == g.subId) then
      Enemy.TriggerEvent ("IntercomMessage"..Enemy.toString (data[4]), data[2], unpack (data, 5))
    end
  end
end


function Enemy.IntercomJoin (name, pChannel)
  g.name = pChannel
  g.subId = name
  
  g.isReady = true
  Enemy.UI_Icon_Switch (true)
  
  
  --Enemy.JoinChannel (g.name, function (name, channel, channelId)
  --[[
  Enemy.JoinChannel (name, function (name, channel, channelId)
    g.channel = channel
    g.channelId = channelId
    g.isReady = true
    Enemy.UI_Icon_Switch (true)
  end)
  ]]--
end

function Enemy.CanSendIntercomMessage ()
    return (g.isReady == true)
end

function Enemy.IntercomSendMessage (key, text)
  
    if (not Enemy.CanSendIntercomMessage ()) then return end
    g.queue[key] =
    {
        key = key,
        text = text,
        t = Enemy.time
    }
    local task_name = "intercom "..Enemy.toString (key)
    if (Enemy.GetTask (task_name) ~= nil) then return end
    
    Enemy.AddTaskAction (task_name, function ()
        
    local q = g.queue[key]
        
            -- abort if intercom not ready
    if (q == nil or not Enemy.CanSendIntercomMessage ()) then return true end
            
            -- wait if can't send chat message
    if (not Enemy.CanSendChatMessage ()) then return false end
            
            -- sending
    local text = q.text
    local sendText = L""
    if (type (text) == "function") then text = text () end
      local gtype = getGroupType()
      local data = Enemy.Split(text, L":")
      if (data[2] == L"Mark") then
        Enemy.TriggerEvent ("IntercomMessage"..Enemy.toString(data[2]), Enemy.playerName, unpack (data, 3))
      end
      --local testText = L".alert !someContact! "..Enemy.playerName..L":"..Enemy.toWString(g.subId)..L":"..Enemy.toWString (text)
      --d(testText)
      if (getGroupType() ~= 1) then
        for index, contact in ipairs(contactList) do
          sendText = L".alert "..Enemy.toWString(contact)..L" "..Enemy.playerName..L":"..Enemy.toWString(g.subId)..L":"..Enemy.toWString (text)
          SendChatText (sendText, L"")
    --d(sendText)
        end
      end
      g.queue[key] = nil
      return true

  end)
end
```

My problem is at the very bottom of the code in

```
for index, contact in ipairs(contactList) do 
sendText = L".alert "..Enemy.toWString(contact)..L" "..Enemy.playerName..L":"..Enemy.toWString(g.subId)..L":"..Enemy.toWString (text)
          SendChatText (sendText, L"")
```

where contactList doesn't seem to get iterated through properly.

On issuing relevant command the message is sent properly, but only to one other person in the group instead of sending it to everyone one-by-one.

- Person 1 in group sends message to person 2 only
- Person 2 to person 1 only
- Person 3 to person 1 only

Expected behavior is message is sent in order to contact[1],contact[2] etc.

I'm a bit lost as to why and I've tried throttling the messages as I thought maybe that's why it only sends to one, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: what is this? In plain Lua `L".alert "`  is  a syntax error.

Comment: A server function that alerts playerX on a hidden server channel. It works just fine the way it is written, but it only sends it to a single person.

Comment: You are definig function `getGroupNames` after using.

Comment: That's not it, I just didn't order them in place will do it now.

Comment: why is there a `)` on the second to last `end` that is a syntax error. the code provided does not appear to properly demonstrate the issue can you try to make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you should mention what you are scripting for. what API is this? you say player. what game API? this is invalid Lua syntax unless somebody added a few extras. also you should post your actual code. not just say "that's not it I'll change it" once we've pointed out mistakes. please read [ask]

Comment: dead game API - Warhammer Online that got shutdown 8 years ago
sorry about not posting the syntax in order in the first place, I've been at this all night and it's bugging me really bad...

the full code is there - it's a rework of an existing addon so I'm not working with my own code either.

Comment: so I guess L is some localization function then. are you sure contactList is properly populated? the sending part looks like it should work for all contacts in the list

Comment: correct, L is basically the send to chat function -

I assume the contactList is populated properly because it knows to send a message to contact 1 if you are contact2 or contact3, and contact1 can send to contact2 as well.

Comment: what does `for k,v in pairs(contactList) do print(k,v) end`  output?

Comment: I'm starting to think it has to do with the throttle timer on chatsend, because I've just tested it in a group with `for k,v in pairs(contactList) do print(k,v) end` and it populates properly getting all the names correctly